# Docker with MySQL v5.7 connection issues

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker on Windows 10 pro-OS, Now I installed Mysql/Mysql-server: latest from docker-compose, actually MySQL is working fine but whenever I try to login its says access denied message from docker panel.

[image]

can anyone tell me what's wrong did?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You use Environment Variables in your Docker-compose ?

Like :

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

Please

Comment: Hello @N Ma, I tried this code but not working, docker run --name mysql/mysql-server -P 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456789

Comment: What are the commands you use before the Docker run?

Comment: docker run <IMAGE ID>